# Is it a good idea to include specific funding calls that I have identified for research topics in my research statement/cover letter?

Tags: computer-science, faculty-application, application-cover-letter, assistant-professor, netherlands

I am applying for a position of an Assistant Professor in computer science at a university in the Netherlands. In my research statement, I have described a number of research directions and in particular, I have identified relevant funding calls for two of the research directions. Could academics who are familiar with the Netherlands system advise me on if it is a good idea to include specific funding calls in the research statement and the cover letter? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Good to include as long as those research funding calls are suitable for your research directions. It shows your knowledge about research funding calls and it can be a plus point.

Comment: In most cases, it might be a very small plus point that, in isolation, won't matter a lot. But then, a large enough number of small plus points can eventually become a less small plus point.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Totally agree!